# ponyorm and python: Postgresql Cannot use composite key when one of the key is auto increment i.e serial or identity

Tags: postgresql, ponyorm

When using pony orm, if primary key is a composite key and one of the key contains postgresql identity column then pony ORM shows error

There is a good reason for me to use a composite key as a primary key instead of just the identity column, and it has to be a composite key

Errors

```
None type Object not iterable
If obj._pk_is_composite_: pairs = izip(pk_attrs, pkval)
```

MOdel

```
id = Required(int, auto=True) 
clubname = Required(str)
PrimaryKey(clubname,id)
```

Table

```
id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
clubname character varying(128),
CONSTRAINT abc PRIMARY KEY(clubname,id)
```

Comment: This needs more information; 1) The model declaration in the ORM 2) The table as shown on Postgres 3) The complete error message. Add this information as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks. Added the required details to the question.

Comment: From here [Keyword arguments](https://docs.ponyorm.org/api_reference.html#keyword-argument-options) `auto=true` can only be used with `PrimaryKey` attribute not `Required`. You might try `id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)` and then `composite_key(id, clubname)` which make ` UNIQUE` key over `id,clubname`.

Answer (score -1):

There is no good for having a composite Primary Key with one component is auto generated. I think what you are trying to say is that `clubname` should be unique, if so your composite key does not accomplish that as (clubname,id) values ('A',1) and ('A',2) satisfy your composite key. Instead just create a unique constraint on `clubname` itself.

```
create table some_table(
             id         integer generated always as identity
           , clubname   character varying(128) not null,
           , constraint some_table_pk primary key(id) 
           , constraint some_table_bk unique (clubname)
           );
```